# Blender 3.5 (Windows 10) - Materials do not apply to mesh objects converted from Empty Hair Curves

Tags: materials, hair

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Add an Empty Hair curve object to a mesh object (for example, the default cube object).
2. Add some hair in Sculpt mode with the curve object.
3. Give the curve object a material with any color except black.
4. Make sure the Viewport is in Rendered shading mode and notice that the color applied to the hair created in step 2.
5. Convert the curve object into a mesh object, and notice that the hair color is lost and becomes black.
6. Try to give the newly converted mesh object a material and notice that the hair does not change color according to the material.

It seems that this issue was not mentioned anywhere including blender.org website.

Comment: Once you'v converted your curves to mesh it's a completely different type of object, why did you want to convert?

Comment: I wanted the conversion so I can exclude the hair from certain lights using the Light Linking new feature starting from 3.6 alpha. It seems the new feature doesn't work on hair curve objects. The problem is that the newly converted mesh object doesn't work with any materials. It looks like it is a cluster of lines with vertices and edges without any faces and UV mappings.